# compare objects in priority queue

Tags: java

I implemented a priority queue with linked list like this,when for first time I make an object from seller class and add it to priority queue, it works, but when I make second object from seller to
add it to priority queue,it gives an error, I know that my comparator makes this error, but I don't 
know, how can I compare objects, please help me!

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class PQueueTest {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        DefaultComparator<Seller> o = new DefaultComparator<>();
        Seller s = new Seller("ali", 125, 200);
        Seller s1 = new Seller("hasan", 50, 100);
        PriorityQueue<Seller> p = new PriorityQueue<>(o);

        p.add(s);
        p.add(s1);

        System.out.println(p.removeMin());
        System.out.println(p.removeMin());
    }

}

class Node<E> {

    private E element;
    private Node<E> next;

    public Node(E element, Node<E> next) {
        this.element = element;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<E> next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void setElement(E element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public Node<E> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public E getElement() {
        return element;
    }
}

class DefaultComparator<E> implements Comparator<E> {

    @Override
    public int compare(E a, E b) {
        return ((Comparable<E>) a).compareTo(b);
    }
}

class PriorityQueue<E> {

    private int size;
    private Node<E> front;
    private DefaultComparator<E> c;

    public PriorityQueue(Comparator<? super E> o) {
        size = 0;
        front = null;
        c = (DefaultComparator<E>) o;

    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public void add(E element) {
        Node<E> v = new Node<>(element, null);
        if (isEmpty()) {
            front = v;
        }

        if (size >= 1) {
            Node<E> temp = front;

            int comp = c.compare(element, temp.getElement());
            while (comp >= 0 && temp.getNext() != null) {
                temp = temp.getNext();
                comp = c.compare(element, temp.getElement());
            }

            if (comp < 0) {
                // E x = temp.getElement();
                v.setNext(temp);
                if (temp == front)
                    front = v;
                else {
                    Node<E> tmp = front;
                    while (tmp.getNext() != temp) {
                        tmp = tmp.getNext();
                    }
                    tmp.setNext(v);
                }
            }

            if (comp >= 0)
                temp.setNext(v);
        }
        size++;
    }

    public E removeMin() {
        E remove = front.getElement();
        front = front.getNext();
        size--;
        return remove;
    }

    public E removeMax() {
        Node<E> tmp = front;
        while (tmp.getNext().getNext() != null) {
            tmp = tmp.getNext();
        }
        E remove = tmp.getNext().getElement();
        tmp.setNext(null);
        size--;
        return remove;

    }

    public E peekMin() {
        E remove = front.getElement();
        return remove;
    }

    public E peekMax() {
        Node<E> tmp = front;
        while (tmp.getNext().getNext() != null) {
            tmp = tmp.getNext();
        }
        E remove = tmp.getNext().getElement();
        return remove;
    }

}

class Seller {

    private String name;
    private long price;
    private int stock;

    public Seller(String name, long price, int stock) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPrice(long price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setStock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public long getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

}

class Buyer {

    private String name;
    private long price;
    private int stock;

    public Buyer(String name, long price, int stock) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPrice(long price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setStock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public long getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you understand what a comparator is and why what you've provided isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: The error is that the cast to Comparable fails. I.e., this line of code:

```
return ((Comparable<E>)a).compareTo(b);
```

The reason for that is, that `a`  (in your case, an instance of `Seller`) does not implement the Comparable interface. You want to compare instances of `Seller`, so `Seller` needs to implement the interface (and the corresponding methods):

```
class  Seller implements Comparable<Seller> {
```

**However** you should be aware that Comparator and Comparable are usually two opposing concepts. While the implementation of Comparable allows instances of a class to compare themselves with other instances of that class, with a Comparator this comparison is encapsuled inside another class. Combining those concept usually makes no sense.

So you should

- Understand what, why and how you should compare
- Decide on one of the two concepts (Comparable or Comparator). Googling this should bring up good results.
- If it's the Comparator, assert that only those types can be passed to your Comparator that can be handled by it (hint: take a look at the generic parameter)

And last but not least: Take a look at the warnings your IDE gives you about type safety. Understand them and you will find the major flaw in your code.